# Mockito behaviors called incorrectly

Tags: java, mockito

I have some Mockito behaviors defined and I also have verboseLogging turned on trying to debug why my test is failing.  I see in the log that some of the methods are being called with either empty or null parameters, which I am not doing.

```
DataTypeService dataTypeService = Mockito.mock(DataTypeService.class, withSettings().verboseLogging());
when(dataTypeService.isMultivalued(anyString())).thenReturn(true);
```

I see this in the log:

```
dataTypeService.isMultivalued("");
invoked: -> at com.example.rest.service.api.v3.impl.ContentServiceImplTest.getDocumentBySchemaMultiValueTest(ContentServiceImplTest.java:186) 
has returned: "false" (java.lang.Boolean)
```

I see something similar in the log for all of my other when statements as well.  They return null instead of what I have in the thenReturn and then it continues and returns the proper item on a second call; however, I am only calling it once.  Does defining a when statement, execute it under the covers with no params?

Comment: Try switching your when statement to this: doReturn(true).when(dataTypeService).isMultiValued(anyString())

Comment: Nope....now it returns null instead of false

Comment: Make sure you aren't using EasyMock or some other framework that has Matchers in it. I've hit weird issues when we migrated from EasyMock to Mockito and I accidentally left an import in for EasyMock in a test and saw weird issues. Check your imports for any other frameworks. I know it's a long shot but I thought I'd mention it.

Comment: Nope, no other frameworks in my test or even in my pom file!

Comment: Have you put a debug point in your code that you are testing at the point where you are calling dataTypeService.isMultivalued to make sure that you are in fact not ever calling it with an empty or null String? Also, Can you post your entire JUnit test?

Comment: Please provide also version of mockito which You are using. Mockito returns default value for Booleans which is false. Im a little bit confused when read that such method returns nulls. Maybe You use version of mockito. This log which You attach is a first method called during recording behaviour of this mock. All the next invocation of your mock should return true.

Answer (score 0):

> Does defining a when statement, execute it under the covers with no
>   params?

Kind of. When you use [anyString()](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyString%28%29) Mockito puts some [internal state](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/internal/progress/ArgumentMatcherStorage.html) and then returns a default value (as stated in the [anyString() Javadoc](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#anyString%28%29)).
After doing that, it calls the mocked object with the default value returned by the `Matcher`, recording its calling internally to associate with a posterior call to `thenReturn` or `thenThrow`. But a mock with no recorded state yet will return a [default answer](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/MockSettings.html#defaultAnswer%28org.mockito.stubbing.Answer%29), which is `false` in your case. So when you `verboseLogging()` it logs the recording call, printing the first `false`. But, after the recording, your mock is good to go, returning the expected value in the second and subsequent calls. Therefore, what you're seeing is just Mockito being Mockito, nothing wrong with that. :)